# Batch script to delete folders but exclude 'prep' word

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for script which will remove all folders containing *del* word in the end of the name but exclude containing *prep* word.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b ?*del') do rd /s /q %%i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b ?*del') do echo %%i | find /i "prep" >nul || rd /s /q "%%i"
```

Comment: Please put the question as answered !